# maven circular dependency + inheritance best practice

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have a few projects in the following structure: Project A, B, C

They are all under a parent project D. in pom.xml under D folder:

```
<module>A</module>
<module>B</module>
<module>C</module>
```

The dependency among them is like : A<--B<--C.

And A,B,C are sharing lots of common dependencies.

1.What's the best practice to organize the dependencies in this case in order to make sub poms very light, also the duplicated dependencies are excluded?

2.What should be put into "dependencies" section and what should be put into "dependency-management" section of the parent pom?

3.common dependencies are more like:

```
log4j, slf4j, thrift, jetty, javax.servlet etc...
```

most of them are transitive dependencies other than directly required by my projects. Does it make sense put them in the parent D's pom.xml as dependencies, let the sub projects(A,B,C) to inherit them from D? I noticed that if you do so, mvn dependency:tree is going to give you warning like.

```
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found: log4j, slf4j ....
```

If that gives me warning, I assume it's something maven doesn't recommend u to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Most important: Only declare dependencies directly required by a module. It is difficult to suggest anything specific without knowing more about your modules and their dependencies. What are examples for common dependencies in your case? Maybe reorganizing your modules helps in reducing common dependencies. Depending on your project it might be reasonable to put all classes from your modules A, B and C that depend on the same artifact into a new module E.
2. In my opinion nothing should be put into the dependencies section in the parent pom (and seeing the warning, it seems maven feels the same ;-)). At least put all the versions of dependencies used in more than one module into the dependency-management section of your parent. This helps to always stay at the same version of a specific dependency over your whole project.
3. As in 2. you should only specify the version of these artifacts in your dependencies-management section in the parent and repeat them in each module that needs it without specifying version. As stated in 1. you should only specify the direct dependencies. For example if you are using slf4j you should only need log4j in the module containing your main class.

To sum up:

- Declare only direct dependencies of a module, transitive dependencies are handled automatically by maven (this is one of the main reasons to use maven at all).
- Only declare needed dependencies: For example in the case of slf4j you only need one module depending on `slf4j-log4j12`, all the other modules need only to depend on slf4j-api.
- Define versions in your parent pom so all submodules use the same version. Do this in the `dependencyManagement` section like this:

  `<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.6.4</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>`
- For each module specify all direct dependencies in the modules pom but without version like this:

  `<dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>`

To handle a lot of dependencies that are shared by a lot of modules you can also use this method: Create a new "dependency collection module" (let's call it `X`) that does nothing but depend on each needed artifact. Now each module only needs to depend on `X` to automatically depend on its dependencies too. I don't recommend this method though because (among other reasons) now each module relies on the dependencies in `X` and you cannot be sure what happens if you remove a dependency from `X` and you need to look at more than one pom to find a modules direct dependencies.

Hope this helps a bit :-)

Comment: I edited my question, and put some examples common dependency examples. So you are saying it's preferable to declare the dependency in the parent pom, and repeatedly have them as dependencies in the sub pom without declaring version?

Comment: @Shengjie I updated my answer and added the "To sum up" section. Yes, at least I prefer doing it this way. But maybe someone else prefers another method of handling dependencies. This is of course not the only true and single way of doing it… ;-)